# CSS gradient stops and repeats

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS gradient in my stylesheet. The problem I have is that the colour goes from `#FFFFFF` to `#EBEBEB`, but when there is a lot of content on a page and you have to scroll down the gradient repeats itself, where the further down the page it should stay `#EBEBEB`.

Below is the code:

```
body {
  /* Safari 4-5, Chrome 1-9 */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#FFFFFF), to(#EBEBEB));

  /* Safari 5.1, Chrome 10+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF, #EBEBEB);

  /* Firefox 3.6+ */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF, #EBEBEB);

  /* IE 10 */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF, #EBEBEB);

  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF, #EBEBEB);
}
```

Can anybody help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: In which browser are you seeing this? I can't reproduce in FF10. What's the minimum page height in px to recreate this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this helps: `no-repeat`

```
html {
  background-color: #EBEBEB;
}    
body {
    /* fallback */
  background-color: #EBEBEB;

  /* Safari 4-5, Chrome 1-9 */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#FFFFFF), to(#EBEBEB)) no-repeat;

  /* Safari 5.1, Chrome 10+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF, #EBEBEB) no-repeat;

  /* Firefox 3.6+ */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF, #EBEBEB) no-repeat;

  /* IE 10 */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF, #EBEBEB) no-repeat;

  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF, #EBEBEB) no-repeat;
}​
```

Comment: I have tried the no repeat but nothing, and adding html background colour changes different aspects on my website.

Comment: I've made an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/fB9Wk/ Doesn't repeat on my computer. Perhaps you have additional CSS, that makes the mess. Have you got a URL?

Comment: Ok thanks. I don't have a URL I got it running on localhost. Ill have a play around with things.

Comment: Try to isolate the code and test it on jsfiddle.net. If the error still is there, you now, it is in this code, if not it must be somewhere else. If you still have erronious code, save the fiddle and post here the url

Comment: It would be easier to just add `background-repeat: no-repeat;` at the end, instead of adding `no-repeat` to each `background` declaration.

Comment: Possibly: But we are not here for perfect code. It is the problem solving, we're here for.